# After assigning a variable a value in Prolog, program ouptut changes from `yes` to `no`

Tags: prolog, logic

I have a simple task of finding the position of an array in another array. BTW, I'm using GNU Prolog 1.4.5.

```
parse([], _) :- true. %parsed sub means that we found it
parse([SHead|STail], [Head|Tail]) :-
    write(SHead), write(' '), write(STail), write(' | '), write(Head), write(' '), write(Tail), nl,
    (
        SHead =:= Head ->
            parse(STail, Tail)
        ;
            false
    )
.

findsub([_|_], [], _) :- false.    %unparsed sub & empty string means there is no sub
findsub([SHead|STail], [Head|Tail], Pos) :-
    (
        var(Pos) -> Pos = 0 ; true %first-time init
    ),
    XPos is Pos + 1,
    (
        SHead =:= Head ->
            (
                parse(STail, Tail) ->
                    true %subarray found
                ;
                    findsub([SHead|STail], Tail, XPos) %continue to next el
            )
        ;
            findsub([SHead|STail], Tail, XPos)
    )
.
```

The program works correctly, but I can't find a way to properly set the value of the `Pos` variable, so it would return an actual position. Add of `Pos is XPos,` after `parse(STail, Tail) ->` , changes the program behaviour to incorrect. I don't understand why. Data for test: `findsub("a", "sdfsfgasfdsfsdf", Pos).`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in Prolog there is no assignment operation (as in procedural languages). The `=/0` operator is used for **term unification**.

Looking into your code, we can start by simplifying the `parse/2` predicate:

```
parse([], _). %parsed sub means that we found it
parse([SHead|STail], [Head|Tail]) :-
    write(SHead), write(' '), write(STail), write(' | '),
    write(Head), write(' '), write(Tail), nl,
    SHead =:= Head, 
    parse(STail, Tail).
```

For your `findsub/3` predicate, you will need to use an *accumulator*, i.e. an auxiliary argument to carry the current position, incrementing it when doing a recursive call:

```
findsub(SList, List, Position) :-
    findsub(SList, List, 1, Position).

findsub([_|_], [], _, _) :-
    % unparsed sub & empty string means there is no sub
    false.
findsub([SHead|STail], [Head|Tail], Position0, Position) :-
    (   SHead =:= Head ->
        (   parse(STail, Tail) ->
            % subarray found
            Position = Position0
        ;   % continue to next element
            Position1 is Position0 + 1,
            findsub([SHead|STail], Tail, Position1, Position)
        )
    ;   Position1 is Position0 + 1,
        findsub([SHead|STail], Tail, Position1, Position)
    ).
```

Your sample call:

```
| ?- findsub("a", "sdfsfgasfdsfsdf", Pos).

Pos = 7
yes
```